# Updating an array with a conditional for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, underscore.js

I have two arrays with different types of complex objects. If there is a certain match of values between objects of each array then I need to take a few values from one of the matching objects and save it. If a few key value pairs from within a matching object get saved then it needs to be removed from its array so that it does not get saved more than once.

The following is my best effort (so far to show an example of what I'm trying to do).

I want to update my empty array based on the code that follows.  This is a simple example to illustrate a much more complex problem and I think it's probably a better way to go than cutting and pasting dozens of lines of code.  The issue has to do with collecting values in the emptyArray and filtering array2 during each passing of the outer loop.  Suggestions leading with underscore are not helpful.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var emptyArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     var something = array[i];
     var array2 = _.without(array2, emptyArray);
     for (a = 0; a < array2.length; a++){
         var value = array2[a];
          if(something === value){
              emptyArray.push(value);
              break;
          }
     }
}
```

I want to update the values in array2 based on the if statement so that those values are not repeated in the nested loop. Instead my emptyArray remains empty instead of adding values from the array2 as elements of array2 are equal to elements of array.

To be clear, right now emptyArray remains empty and never filters array2.
I'd like to see empty array collect value 2 at the start of the outer loop's second iteration then I'd like to see emptyArray collect value 4 at the start of the 4th iteration of the outer loop.

I'd want to filter each of these values from array2 as they become part of emptyArray so that they do not set off the if statement during the 6th and 8th iterations of the outer loop.  I imagine that emptyArray = [2, 4] and array2 = [6, 8, 10] when the loops are finished.

Comment: If you are going to give me a minus, could you please at least say why?

Comment: Perhaps if you provided examples of expected output that might help. I don't see how that code could work, for example, because there are no elements in `array` to loop over.

Comment: thanks! I'll update it now!

Comment: Ok, so you want to move the common items that are in `array` and `array2` into `emptyArray`

Comment: The code is actually a bit more complex than that but I'm trying to create a simple example that illustrates my issue.  I need to collect the values in the emptyArray and hold them for updating as shown in the example.

Comment: This is an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the _problem_ you are trying to solve  rather than the _solution_ you think solves it.

Comment: I have two arrays with different types of complex objects.  If there is a certain match of values between objects of each array then I need to take a few values from one of the matching objects and save it.  If values of the object get saved then it needs to be removed out of the array so that it does not get saved more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function `_.without` doesn't take an array as second argument, it takes individual items to be removed. e.g `_.without(ar1,1,2,3)`
If you need to pass an array use `_.difference(ar1, ar2)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using underscore, this can be much simpler.

```
emptyArray = _.intersection(array, array2)
array2 = _.difference(array2, emptyArray)
```

Comment: Again, thanks for getting back to me on this. As I mention above, the code is more complex so it actually can't be simpler than the code shown above. It's an adding values to an array while looping issue made more tricky because it's changing the length of the loop as it iterates.